# Como passar para a função qual imageView foi selecionada e salvar no Firebase

Tags: java, android, imageview

Tenho uma Activity de Cadastro de usuario onde ele deve preencher alguns campos( nome, sexo, idade, etc) e duas ImageView onde o usuario pode colocar fotos dele, clicando na ImageView e selecionando elas na galeria.

Tenho o metodo selecionaFoto setado como onClick nas duas ImageView, após o usuario escolher a foto no onActivityResult, ele pega a foto selecionada e chama a função setImagem para colocar a foto na ImageView. Quero que a foto selecionada apareça no ImageView que ele clicou e é ai que começa o problema.

Como passo para a função de setar imagem a ImageView que o usuario clicou, para que ela seja colocada na ImageView correta?

E como salvar as imagens no Firebase Storage e Database, para poder acessa-las em outra activity(url)?

Segue código:

```
public class Anunciante extends AppCompatActivity {

    StorageReference storageRef;
    DatabaseReference databaseUsuario;

    private ImageView imgPrincipal, img02;
    private EditText txtNome, txtValor, txtDescricao, txtFone;
    private Spinner spIdade, spSexo;
    private Uri imgUri, imgUri2;

public static final String FB_STORAGE_PATH = "imagem/";
public static final String FB_DATABASE_PATH = "Anuncios";
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_01 = 1910;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_02 = 2015;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);


    storageRef = getStorage();
    databaseUsuario = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase();

    imgPrincipal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPrincipalAnuncio);
    imgPrincipal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione sua foto!"), REQUEST_CODE_01);

        }
    });
    img02 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img02);
    img02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione sua foto!"), REQUEST_CODE_02);

        }
    });

    txtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
    txtValor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtValor);
    txtFone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFone);
    txtDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
    spIdade = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spIdade);
    spSexo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spSexo);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_01 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        imgUri = data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgUri);
            imgPrincipal.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_02 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        imgUri2 = data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgUri2);
            img02.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getExtImagem(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
}

@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
public void salvaDados(View v){

    if (imgUri != null){
        StorageReference reference = getStorage().child(FB_STORAGE_PATH + FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseUser().getUid() + "principal"+"." + getExtImagem(imgUri));
        reference.putFile(imgUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()  {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Upload upload = new Upload(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString().trim(),
                        taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString().trim(), txtNome.getText().toString(),
                        spIdade.getSelectedItem().toString()+" anos", spSexo.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        "R$ " + txtValor.getText().toString()+",00",
                        txtFone.getText().toString(), txtDescricao.getText().toString());
                String uid = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseUser().getUid();
                databaseUsuario.child(uid).setValue(upload);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            }
        });
    }
    goMainScreen();
}



public void goMainScreen() {
    Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(main);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode substituir o ImageView por um ImageButton, ele fornece suporte ao clique.

E usar o seu método  `public void selecionaFoto(View v)` para ser o onClick do ImageButton, o parâmetro View v deve fornecer qual ImageButton foi clicado.

Comment: Exatamente isso que não sei como fazer, troquei os 2 ImageView por ImageButton, coloquei o metétodo selecionaFoto como onClick nos dois.

Comment: agora no selecionarFoto vc faz assim:  if(v.getId() == R.id.imageButton1){ }, tente essa implementacao, eu fiz rapido e nao testei.

Comment: Aleluia, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente! Só preciso otimizar o carregamento da imagem, pois ficou meio lento mas isso eu consigo resolver.

Comment: Você estava fazendo tudo certo, só precisava saber juntar as peças

Comment: Corrigindo, funcionou, mas so aparece a foto selecionada apos clicar novamente no ImageButton...

Comment: Se não estou enganado eu deveria chamar o setImagem dentro do onActivityResult, para que a foto que eu selecionei preencha o imageButton correto, mas não funciona, so funciona quando chamo o setImagem dentro do selecionaFoto

Comment: Faz assim: cria uma variavel para armazenar a imageButton que foi clicada e no selecionaFoto você salva a view, então no onActivityResult voce chama o setImagem alterando a view do imagemButton

Comment: Não faço ideia de como fazer o que vc disse, mas vou dar uma pesquisada e tentar fazer

Comment: Consegui realizar o que eu queria, (não sei se o que fiz foi o que você me explicou, só a parte de salvar os dados que não funcionou ainda, pois esta gravando a ultima foto selecionada na galeria duas vezes no Firebase.